# How do I show a JS variable on the TITLE tag?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="timer"></p>
  <script>
  var a = 30;
  var b = 1;

  var c = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = a - b;
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for taking your time to look at this!

How would I show `VARIABLE C` inside the HTML `TITLE` tag??

so:

```
<title>SHOW WHAT VARIABLE c IS EQUAL TO</title>
```

The point for this is to make a countdown timer that will show your time in your tab so you don't have to keep checking. 
Also, right now it just subtracts 1, how would I make it KEEP subtracting??

THANK YOU!!

I appreciate it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `document.title`, like so

```
  var a = 30;
  var b = 1;

  var c = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = a - b;
  document.title = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in javascript

```
  var a = 30;
  var b = 1; 
  var c = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = a - b;
  window.document.title = c;
```

Comment: wooooooow! MIND = BLOWN. Okay, thanks. I never knew you could do this. THANKS, MAN!